# Can I get the string from a git command return?

Tags: git, githooks

I'm using git hooks and want to pull before pushing, so, I create the pre-push file. Also, I want to guarantee that my pull return is "Already up to date.". Can I get that string to create an if or something?

I expect to push to my repo if the return from pull is "Already up to date."

Comment: In a script, you'd probably be better off using the command's exit code, because porcelain outputs are unreliable and may change with git versions.

Comment: What script-language are you using in your hook? Can you post the contents of your hook?

Answer (score 2):

After your pull you could check

```
git log --format='%H' HEAD..HEAD@{upstream}
```

This command will list the IDs of commits that are on HEAD's *upstream* branch, but **not** HEAD.

If the output of this command is *empty*, then HEAD *is* up-to-date with upstream. (0 commits behind)

Notes:

- If you want to detect commits that HEAD is *ahead* of its upstream, reverse the order: `git log --format='%H' HEAD@{upstream}..HEAD`
- If you want to list commits that HEAD is ahead **and** also commits that HEAD is behind = all commits that are not shared by both HEAD and its upsteam but are unique to one or the other, use 3 dots instead of two: `git log --format='%H' HEAD...HEAD@{upstream}`
- As *Romain Valeri* pointed out in a comment above, it would probably be wiser to just check if the command `git pull` resulted in exit code `0`; indicating that both its fetch and its merge were successful - which implies that HEAD was either up-to-date before the pull or was successfully brought to up-to-date state by the pull command.
- If you want your `git pull` to not attempt a merge automatically when there is an difference in the commit history between HEAD and its upstream, add `--ff-only`. `git pull --ff-only` will abort if there are commits on upstream that would require a merge ( = HEAD is both ahead and behind at the same time).